# Is there any two objects that as the distance increases between them so do the forces of attraction?

Tags: electromagnetism, material-science, spring, ferromagnetism

I was wondering if anyone knew if there were any 2  distinct objects such that as the distance between them grew, so did their mutual forces of attraction. Is there a way to manipulate two objects so that this occurs?

To give context, I was wondering why no one has built a remote dog leash (the person holds an object in his hand, and as the dog gets farther away, the dog’s collar and the object in the person’s hand pull each other with greater force) and I figured that this is the main reason why no one has made it.

FlinnBella

Comment: That's how the strong force holds protons and neutrons together

Comment: Quarks behave like this. The nuclear strong force increases with range - it's like they're held together with a spring.

Comment: Can that same force be applied over greater distance such as 1-2 feet?

Comment: None of the large-scale fundamental forces (gravitational/electrostatic) obey this but you can certainly just tie a rubber band to two objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple take the two objects and tie them together with an elastic rope (for simplicity assume unbreakable rope) then it happens that the force acting on each object increases as the distance between the two increases. Now if you are talking of a fundamental force then strong nuclear force would be a great example as it has such properties though it might not be of any use(as of your case) as it is quite short range force.